# Using glob.glob to pick random files gives weird errors

Tags: python, glob, moviepy

I'm using this method to pick random files of a certain type from a folder a user inputs, and then concentate them together in MoviePy:

```
 filename = glob.glob(input +"/*.mp3")
sdofjsodfj = random.choice(filename)
aclips.append(AudioFileClip(sdofjsodfj))
random.shuffle(aclips)
filename = glob.glob(input + "/*.mp4")
clipname = random.choice(filename)
lend = random.uniform(.5, VideoFileClip(clipname).duration)
end = clipname
finalclip = VideoFileClip(end).subclip(lend - .5, lend).fx(vfx.speedx, random.uniform(.54, 3)).resize((250, 250))
```

However, this method sometimes works, but most of the time returns this error:

```
IndexError: Cannot choose from an empty sequence
```

Is there a reason why it would be doing this?

Comment: What's  `input` for?

Comment: You are trying to use `random.choice` on an empty list.

Comment: @SeyiDaniel Input is the path to the video/audio files provided by the users

Comment: @MauriceMeyer Shouldn't the list not be empty since i'm doing glob.glob on it?

Answer (score 0):

It simply means there are no `.mp4` files in the directory you globbed (you may possibly have other file types in there but not `mp4`). And so an empty list is returned as `filename`.

Comment: But I have tons of mp4s and mp3s in there... and sometimes it finds them in the glob but other times it doesn't for whatever odd reason